# windows-8 keyboard-shortcuts for Charms is lost

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, charms-bar

I was able to use <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as the (standard) shortcut for opening the Charms bar, but not any more now.

I don't know what's wrong and I want to get that shortcut back.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: are you on a laptop or desktop?

Comment: desktop, newly installed not long ago